# \psaxes: showorigin=true and origin label overlaps axis

Tags: pst-plot

Feeding `mwe.tex` containing

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}%
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1.6)(1.6,1.6)
  \psaxes{->}(0,0)(0,-1.5)(1.5,1.5)
\end{pspicture}%
\end{document}
```

to `latex mwe && dvipdf -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY mwe` results in the lower 0 overlapping the vertical axis:

[image: output]

You could also use `dvips mwe` instead of `dvipdf -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY mwe` and get the same result.

There has been some (apparently) silent change: in 2017, the output had only the left, nonoverlapping 0 but not the lower, overlapping 0.

Moreover, the User's Guide of PSTricks clearly states:

> **showorigin=true/false**
>
> **Default: true**
>
> If true, then labels are placed at the origin, as long as the label doesn’t end up on one of the axes. If false, the labels are never placed at the origin.

The text is formally-logically open on the output when `showorigin` is `true` and a label ends up on one of the axes. Still, in this case, a typical reader would probably expect that the label is not placed at the origin.

How to (vaguely speaking, automatically) get the old behavior back, i.e., such that the left, nonoverlapping label 0 is shown but the lower, overlapping label 0, is not shown?

Comment: I usually use `showorigin=false` , and place the origin by hand with `\uput[l](0;0){$0$}`.

Comment: There are also definitions for separate keys `showXorigin` and `showYorigin` but these do not seem to be implemented (?)

Comment: @Marijn Probably, yes: the current effect of `\psaxes[showXorigin=false,showYorigin=true]{->}(0,0)(0,-1.5)(1.5,1.5)` is for me unfortunately exactly the same as that of `\psaxes{->}(0,0)(0,-1.5)(1.5,1.5)`.

Comment: @Bernard First, thanks. Second, following your suggestion, we'd have to horizontally align the left zero with the other labels of the vertical axis and write something like `\uput[l](-.14;0){$0$}`, where `-.14` is a wild guess and probably depends on the current font. The guessing is incomfortable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}%
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1.6)(1.6,1.6)
\psaxes[showorigin=false]{->}(0,0)(0,-1.5)(1.5,1.5)
\psyTick(0){0}
\end{pspicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could I kindly ask you to take a look at the followup question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/632388 ?