# \psaxes: drop x origin label, retain y origin label, no outer y ticks, horizontal line at negative exponents with logLines=y

Tags: pst-plot

Feeding the file `mwe.tex` containing

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}%
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1.6)(1.6,1.6)
  \psaxes[logLines=y,ylogBase=10,ysubticks=0]{->}(0,0)(0,-1.5)(1.5,1.5)
\end{pspicture}%
\end{document}
```

to `latex mwe && dvipdf -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY mwe` yields

[image: unwished output]

As you see, the zero overlaps the vertical axis, which is unpleasant. Back in 2017, the zero was not printed; there has been a change since then.

Following http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/632377 , I tried

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}%
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1.6)(1.6,1.6)
  \psaxes[logLines=y,ylogBase=10,ysubticks=0,showorigin=false]{->}(0,0)(0,-1.5)(1.5,1.5)
  \psyTick[yticksize=0](0){10^0}
\end{pspicture}%
\end{document}
```

which gives a better outcome:

[image: wished output]

However, the typesetting is somewhat cumbersome: we add a tick with a label but set the size of the tick to zero.

1. Is there a cleaner solution, and, if so, what would it be?
2. Why is there no horizontal line at 10^{-1}? How to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes no sense to me to have the x axis at 10^0. I'D USE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}%
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1.6)(1.6,1.6)
  \psaxes[logLines=y,ylogBase=10,ysubticks=0,showorigin=false,Oy=-1]{->}(0,-1)(1.5,1.5)
  \psyTick[yticksize=0](0){10^0}
  \psyTick[yticksize=0](-1){10^{-1}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you still want it there use `xAxis=false` and `yAxis=false` and write
independent x/y axes, for example:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}%
\begin{pspicture}(-0.5,-2.5)(5.5,5.5)
  \psaxes[logLines=y,ylogBase=10,ticksize=0 5,ysubticks=0,xAxis=false,Oy=-2]{->}(0,-2)(1.5,5)
  \psaxes[yAxis=false,showorigin=false]{->}(0,0)(5,5)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In my concrete (not minimal-working-example) usage case, which I have not shown here, the y values range between 10^{-2} and 10^5. I prefer to have the x axis somewhere inside rather than at the bottom, and y = 10^0 is a natural choice for the position of the x axis.

Comment: @GeekestGeek: see edited answer

Comment: Thx! The number 1.5 in `\psaxes[logLines=y,ylogBase=10,ticksize=0 5,ysubticks=0,xAxis=false,Oy=-2]{->}(0,-2)(1.5,5)` puzzles me: it should probably be either 0 or 5.